# How to get the total price? (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular

I've been trying to get the total price of cart items, but I can't? I tried to do a method that sums all prices and passes it to the template, but I couldn't.

Here is the Cart Component as you can see:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/Model/Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cartList: Product[] = []
  itemQuantities: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  DeleteItem(cartItem: Product){
    const indexOfCartItem = this.cartList.indexOf(cartItem)
    this.cartList.splice(indexOfCartItem, 1)
  }
}
```

Cart Template:

```
<section class="form-section">
  <div class="cart-list">
    <ul *ngFor="let cartItem of cartList">
      <img src="{{ cartItem.img }}" />
      <li>{{ cartItem.name }}</li>
      <li>{{ cartItem.price }}</li>
      <button (click)="DeleteItem(cartItem)">Remove Item</button>
      <div>
        <select>
          <option *ngFor="let itemQuantity of itemQuantities">
            {{ itemQuantity }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <div *ngFor="let carts of cartList"><p>Total price</p></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: How did you tried it? Your ts and template does not have a logic that calculate and show total price. Please share your code that you tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is too simple. Write a function in typescript.

Template (html Component)

```
<div *ngFor="let cart of cartList">
  <p> price - {{ cart.price }} </p>
</div>
<p> Total Price - {{ totalPrice }} </p>
```

(TS Component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css'],
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  cartList = [{ price: 10 }, { price: 20 }, { price: 30 }, { price: 40 }];
  totalPrice = 0;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.calculateTotal();
  }
  calculateTotal() {
    this.cartList.map((cart) => {
      this.totalPrice += cart.price;
    });
  }
}
```

**Evidence**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do it with for loop, but I couldn't make it.

Comment: Seriously ? Please check detail. I write a function in typescript component to calculate total price. It is nothing deals with ng for loop. Just check function. First , declare global variable for total price. And then , loop and make addition to total price . After that , rebind in html with {{totalPrice}}.

Comment: Yeah, I already did. Thank you.

Comment: can I just return this.total price, then pass it in the html template?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't know how to do it , add your code to that Stackblitz (the upper link) . I will check it for you.

Comment: If there is something still wrong , you need to show me your console for cartList. Is there any price value ? what is your cartList console ?

Comment: I did it! Thank you so much for helping me, it worked out! Let explain what I did first before posting this question. I did exactly what you did as I've done it in a problem solving quiz before, but the thing is I didn't change my price: Type in my model, it was a string instead.

Comment: And also, I figured out why I couldn't do it by for loop, lol.